# Seekbar con metodo String.format no accede a un string en kotlin AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, xml, kotlin

Tengo un seekbar que esta intentando acceder a el strings.xml y no me funciona

```
binding.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
            override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
                comensales = p1
                binding.txtComensales.text = String.format(getString(R.string.strcomensales, comensales))
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
                
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
                
            }
        })
```

Este seria mi seekbar, y aqui abajo mi string declarado (Lo que da problemas es arriba el strcomensales

```
    <string name="strcomensales">Comensales: %d personas</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

El código necesario para realizar el formado es correcto, el valor de p1 y comensales es tipo Int por lo tanto se aplicaría correctamente el formato, de hecho puedes imprimir el valor y sabras que se realiza correctamente

```
  override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
                comensales = p1
                val texto: String = String.format(getString(R.string.strcomensales, comensales))
                println(texto); //Imprime valor
                binding.txtComensales.text = texto
            }
```

Se imprimiría algo similar a:

```
Comensales: 2 personas
```

Debes asegurar que esta referencia `binding.txtComensales` en verdad sea de un `TextView` que se este mostrando en la pantalla.